# Imread в cv2 не видит картинку формата jpg

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

вылетает ошибка того, что файл, который я загружаю через imread - пустой / не существует, однако если открыть этот файл через open питона, то все нормально.

Картинка с которой все работает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка, с которой не работает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s. Формат библиотекой поддерживается, пробовал указывать относительные и абсолютные пути. Возникают проблемы не со всеми картинками формата .jpg , а только с некоторыми

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Если картинки не секрет, загрузите файл рабочей картинки и нерабочей, попробуем сравнить их. Возможно, OpenCV не поддерживает какие-то особенные фичи джипега

Comment: попробуйте скопировать тот же файл таким образом чтобы в полном пути были только ASCII символы и попробуйте открыть его `cv.imread` опять...

Comment: Добавил картинки

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была в кодировке. После переименовки файла на латиницу все заработало

Comment: (шёл 2019 год, проблемы с кодировками до сих пор существуют, эх...)

Comment: просто надо путь к файлу экранировать